# JavaFX How to stop cursor from moving to a new line in a TextArea when Enter is pressed

Tags: javafx, textarea

I have a Chat application. I'd like the cursor in the `chatTextArea` to get back to the position 0 of the TextArea `chatTextArea`.

This, however, won't work:

```
chatTextArea.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
            ChatClient.main(new String[]{"localhost", String.valueOf(4444), chatTextArea.getText()});
            chatTextArea.setText("");
            chatTextArea.positionCaret(0);
        }
    }
});
```

How can I get it to work? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TextArea` internally does not use the `onKeyPressed` property to handle keyboard input. Therefore, setting `onKeyPressed` does not remove the original event handler.

To prevent `TextArea`'s internal handler for the Enter key, you need to add an *event filter* that consumes the event:

```
chatTextArea.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
            ChatClient.main(new String[]{"localhost", String.valueOf(4444), chatTextArea.getText()});
            chatTextArea.setText("");
            // chatTextArea.positionCaret(0); // not necessary
            ke.consume(); // necessary to prevent event handlers for this event
        }
    }
});
```

Event *filter* uses the same `EventHandler` interface. The difference is only that it is called before any event *handler*. If an event filter *consumes* the event, no event handlers are fired for that event.