# Javafx TextArea not automatically scrolling

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to create a chatting program when I type a string into "input"(textarea) and press "enter", it will be added to "output"(textarea) and output is the content of the "scroll"(scrollpane). I want it to scroll to the bottom automatically once I press enter and the text in output change. I tried usinga change listener but it doesn't scroll to the bottom. I have searched for this problem but none of the solutions help in my case. Apologies if the code looks messy (new to Java FX)

```
BorderPane border=new BorderPane();
Scene chatScene=new Scene(border,entreeStage.getWidth(),entreeStage.getHeight());
 chatScene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("entreeAurora.css").toExternalForm());

 ToolBar toolbar2=new ToolBar(teach,glueSeparator,exit);toolbar2.setId("toolbar2");
 output=new TextArea();output.setEditable(false);

 ScrollPane scroll=new ScrollPane();
 scroll.setContent(output);
 scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);output.setId("output");
 scroll.setFitToHeight(true);scroll.setFitToWidth(true);

 input =new TextArea();input.setId("input");input.setPrefHeight(175);
 border.setTop(toolbar2);border.setBottom(input);border.setCenter(scroll);
 output.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue,
                Object newValue) {

            output.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE); 
        }
    });
 input_text=input.getText();

 input.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent Event) {
        output_text=output.getText();input_text=input.getText();
        if(Event.getCode()==KeyCode.ENTER) {
            output.setText(output_text+"You: "+input_text+"\n");
            output.appendText("");
            output.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        input.setEditable(false);input.setText("");

        }
        }
     });

     input.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(KeyEvent Event) {
             if(Event.getCode()==KeyCode.ENTER) {
                 input.setEditable(true);

             }
         }
     });
```

Comment: Don't put multipe statements into a single line. This makes the code hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the code you posted in your question and it seems to work fine.

I only deleted `input.setEditable(false)` to add new lines so that textarea reachs its limit and starts to scroll all the way bottom and added `Event.consume()` to the end of input textarea listener so that internal handler of input textarea does not add a new line after each hit to the enter which is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26756898/8555304).